# Pass PDF result to another web api in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, pdf, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a web api which retrieves PDF file stored in database.

```
[HttpGet("file/{id}")]
public IActionResult GetFile(int id)
{
    var file = dataAccess.GetFileFromDB(id);

    HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    FileContentResult result = new FileContentResult(file, "application/pdf")
    {
        FileDownloadName = "test.pdf"
    };

    return result;
}
```

I need to write a wrapper web api which will pass result from the above web api to the client.

What is the best way to achieve this using .NET Core? should I return byte array from the above web api and  convert byte array to FileContentResult in the wrapper api?

Any code sample would be very helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you essentially want a proxy?

Comment: yes, kind of. Client (Angular 2) calls wrapper web api which internally calls db web apis to retrieve the data.

Comment: The easiest way with .NET Core is to use [this project](https://github.com/aspnet/Proxy) as a base for your implementation (it uses a middleware). Or there is a reason to re-implement another API?

Comment: The wrapper API is responsible for few other things as well so unfortunately I have to use wrapper API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try to just reroute the response from an `HttpClient` to the user:

```
using System.Net.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

public class TestController : Controller
{
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var response = await client.GetAsync("http://apiaddress", HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead); // this ensures the response body is not buffered

            using (var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync()) 
            {
                return File(stream, "application/pdf");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will give a try. Just wondering, will it read the PDF content twice? i.e. One at db api level and another at wrapper api level.

Comment: Yes of course, but the second time it should directly stream it to the client.